# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'do'

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I'm not very familiar with Jinja and I'm having some issues using "do" statement in my template. I was reading other posts and I was trying to fix it but still no luck.

Here is how partial output how I try to call it.

**NOTE: my interpreter says that "Extension" is not used:**

```
import jinja2
import csv
from jinja2.ext import Extension


jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.do'])

with open ('mycsv.csv') as f:
    read_csv = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in read_csv:
        with open ( line["name"] +"_config.txt", 'w') as output:                    
            with open(r"My_Template.j2") as t:
                my_templ = t.read()

            temmplate = jinja2.Template(my_templ)
            output.write(temmplate.render(line))
```

Here is just example how I want to use the "do", not the exact template (that is a separate file)

```
{%- for Z in range (1,X+1) %}
{%- do  Y-=1 %}
something {{Z}} something_else {{Y}}
{%- endfor %}
```

Error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'do'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

===== UPDATE ======

Thanks again!That works fine if I define my variables within the Jinja. But if I use variables from a csv I have some issues. I expect output like:

```
increment 1 decrement 14
increment 2 decrement 13
```

So this works fine.

```
{% set one = 1 %}
{% set fourteen = 14 %}
{% set base = 3 %}
{% for inc in range(base) %}
switch {{one+base}} priority {{fourteen - base}}
{% endfor %}
```

But if I try to use variables from the csv,everything is treated like a string. If I remove:

```
{% set base = 3 %}
```

and I get:

```
TypeError: "str" object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
```

So I tried modifying the jinja with:

```
{% set base = int(base) %}
```

and

```
{% set base = integer(base) %}
```

I get below two errors respectively:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: "int" is undefined
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: "integer" is undefined
```

If I change it within the python it says "undefined":

```
base = int(line["base"])
print(base)
print(type(base))

Output:
3
<class 'int'>

  File "<template>", line 6, in top-level template code
TypeError: 'Undefined' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is line 6:

```
{% for inc in range(base) %}
```

Is there a way to tell in the Jinja template that a value is of a type integer?

Comment: It's correct that you're not using the `jinja2.ext.Extension` module. You don't need to import that. It's not clear from your question if you're experiencing an actual problem...is the `do` command working in your templates, or not?

Comment: Hi, it is not working. I updated how the python script looks like and the error I get. The part of the j2 template is at the very top. All variables are taken from CSV and it works fine without the "do" part. 
Is the usage of "do" wrong in the template, or should i reference it somewhere else in the python file? Or maybe something wrong with the extension and the environment...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that while you've enabled the `do` extension in your `jinja_env` Environment, you're not using the environment to fetch your templates. You need to load templates using the `jinja_env.get_template` method if you want your environment settings to be relevant.

For example, assuming that templates were available in the current directory, we could rewrite your code like this:

```
import jinja2
import csv
from jinja2.ext import Extension


jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('.'),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.do']
)

with open ('mycsv.csv') as f:
    read_csv = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in read_csv:
        with open("{name}_config.txt".format(**line), 'w') as output:
            template = jinja_env.get_template('My_Template.j2')
            output.write(template.render(line))
```

You're going to encounter a second problem, which is that your use of
the `do` statement in your example is invalid. You can't write...

```
{% do Y -= 1 %}
```

...because that's not an expression. You can interpret "an expression"
as "something that can go on the right side of an assignment
statement". So these are examples of valid uses of `do`:

```
{% do somevar.append('a value') %}
{% do somedict.setdefault('name', 'alice') %}
```

---

For variable assignment, Jinja has the `{% set ... %}` expression. You can use that to decrement a variable. E.g., this works:

```
{% set x = 5 %}
{% set x = x - 1 %}
```

Unfortunately, set doesn't so much *modify* a variable as much as it
*creates a new one*, which means this won't work inside a `for` loop
because the new variable is scoped to the current loop iteration.
That is, if we were to write:

```
{% set x = 5 %}
{% for y in range(5) %}
{% set x = x - 1 %}
{{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output would be:

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

However, we can get the behavior we're looking for by writing instead:

```
{% set x = 5 %}
{% for y in range(5) %}
{{ x-y }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which will produce:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this later, but I thought I can increment/decrement values within "do" statement with +/-=1

Comment: Well, I tried this, the "do" statement is now recognized, but I'm still confused how to decrement by one in every "for" iteration.

Comment: I've added a few updates addressing your question.

Comment: Hey, thanks again! I've also updated my first post because it is a bit long. In short is there a way to tell in the Jinja template that a value is of a type integer? I tried a couple of things with no luck